# How to connect RPi to display

Tags: display, pi-3b+

I recently purchased a LANDZO 3.5 Inch Touch Screen 320480 for Raspberry Pi 3 Model B (3.5 inch) and when I un-boxed it I realized that it had a large GPIO block on the back of it.  This GPIO block makes it much thicker than it would other wise be.  I can not de-solder it because it is attached firmly to a board that is attached to the display.

Can this GPIO block be removed without ruining the display?  And if it is possible, how do I connect the display to RPi zero or RPi 3 when this GPIO header block is detached?

Thanks for any pointers on this,

BR, G.Gordon

Comment: are you talking about the pin header? ... you can just cut it up using good quality wire cutters

Comment: Yeah, I must be talking about the pin header.  It is huge and triples the depth of an otherwise narrow screen. It is like a black plastic rectangular block with pairs of holes in it that receive the GPIO pins on the RPi3 board.  Can I just break this black part off?

Comment: The part I want to remove is the "female" part connected to the back of the display.

Comment: You do realize that is how the screen gets power, and works as a *touch* screen?  From the looks of things, it uses 8 pins, not including power and ground.  You will have to do something else to make those connections if you remove the plug.  The ribbon cable is just display input.

Comment: I am aware that those pins can provide power but I wasn't sure about the touch screen.  I am hoping to supply power by a micro usb port with an on/off switch that I will solder on the board.  My project will not require a functional touch screen so I will leave it disconnected.

Comment: I think I will have to use the HDMI port on the Rpi to connect the screen, but that means I have to be able to attach an HDMI cable to the board.

Comment: I just noticed that my last comment does not make sense.  I can use the existing port for power or solder an off switch to the board.  Those are 2 different option. And I can use a power supply with a built in switch as well.  Ultimately I want to connect to a battery though.